# Egrep regex end of line not matching properly with $

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sh

My pattern needs to have three words where there is a single SPACE character separating the three tokens in each line.

for example

```
inherit class3 class4
inherit class35 class5
implement class3 interface1
aggregate class3 class5
```

My code is `egrep -i "^[0-9a-z]+\ [0-9a-z]+\ [0-9a-z]+$" "$input2"`

This still does not match it properly and outputs nothing with $ at the end, but if i remove the $, it outputs the lines having more than 3 tokens in each line. I've been trying to make it work perfectly for a really long time but its not working. Thanks.

Test file has this

```
d d d d
 dfsdfg afegsdfh asfg
efgfah afgadfg adfsg 
awg  awg wga
wrhg warg  wrgrw
awdg afsg
sdg

asdg asdg asdg asdg
```

Comment: Oh $input2 is a text file by the way.

Comment: Works fine for me... Did you check that there are no trailing spaces before the end of line ?

Comment: @SheharyarIrfan It is working fine, can show us the output you are getting ?

Comment: @snyder that's a regex match - if it finds no match there is no output...

Comment: Working fine for me too.  The only way I was able to get close to what you're saying is to convert the end of line characters to a different format.  What's the operating system, and did the input file originate from there?

Comment: @alfasin But I am getting the correct output, I think its not regex problem but something else, the regex looks fine.

Comment: Mac os 10.9 is my os and using terminal

Comment: @SheharyarIrfan its hard to test that file as we don't know where the new line occurs, you can add it to your question.

Comment: @snyder Added the test file to the question

Comment: Well, with that test file, you do realize it would never match the pattern and thus will output nothing, correct?  Even the third line has a trailing space after it, so that won't match either.

Comment: @sdanzig Yeah, just realized it works perfectly. I got confused with the trailing space in the 3rd line. Thanks a lot anyways guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the test data, no lines will match the regex.   It is behaving as it should.  You might think it will match the third line, but it can't because there's a trailing space, so the third token is not immediately followed by the end of line.

When you remove the end of line character from the regex pattern, it indeed does not have this constraint, so, as long as the line begins with three tokens separated by a space, it will be matched.  Therefore, the lines, as described by the asker, would print out.

Answer (score 1):

Your test file doesn't seem to have any patterns that exactly match the search... there is a space at the end of the one line that *would* match.

[image]

To solve, add some optional spaces in your search with `*`...

Answer (score 0):

$ is a a regex symbol for end of line. Therefore if you want something to end with $ you should you backslash (as you use near the brackets) - \$. As I see it your command should actually end with \$$

Comment: No, i don't want it to end with $, what i'm trying to say is that $ does not end line properly in the way i've written. Three words in each line is what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 egrep -i "^\ *[0-9a-z]+\ [0-9a-z]+\ [0-9a-z]+\ *$"
```

The command you tried was not working because it doesn't capture the cases when there are spaces in the beginning or end.